# Can Cuban coffee be approximated?

Tags: coffee

On a recent visit to Miami I fell in love with Cuban coffee. It's a great mid-afternoon pick-me-up, but not available where I live. How, if at all, can I approximate it at my office? (There is no stove in the break room, so a stovetop moka pot is not an option, and for a number of reasons I don't want to invest in an espresso machine for the office.)

Comment: There are electric moka pots, but I'm not sure which ones are good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many small hand operated espresso pump that could be used instead of a full fledged espresso machine or mocha pot; you only need hot water.

Once you have your coffee, you can follow the steps needed to create a Cuban Coffee.

Comment: Are you thinking of something like [this](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kitchen/detailpages/aeropress-hero-260.jpg)?

Comment: this and other types